# How to access Origin-Destination data using the Lyft API?

Tags: lyft-api

Does Lyft API access include a way to access historical data, such as for specific time periods? Specifically, I am seeking Origin-Destination data, to identify which locations have the greatest demand for these services.

Comment: Have you considered their documentation?: https://developer.lyft.com/docs/overview

Comment: Yes, looked through it quite extensively before checking here, but found no reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can obtain the origin and destination latitude and longitude via Lyft GET /rides endpoint

Online reference:
https://developer.lyft.com/v1/reference#users-ride-history

However, you will need to use a 3rd party service like Foursquare, Yelp, Google, or Factual to figure out whether the destination venue is residential or commercial.  See below for examples how to query place via via latitude and longitude:

Google Places
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Foursquare Places
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/search